# MongoDB get fieldvalue based on fieldname

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB, and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible at all. I've exhausted my Google skills, so I'm hoping someone here can give me a push in the right direction.

My data is structured like this:

```
db={
  "people": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pete",
      "occupation": "baker"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mike",
      "occupation": "painter"
    }
  ],
  "activity": [
    {
      "baker": "bakes",
      "painter": "paints"
    }
  ]
}
```

Although this is just sample data, my "activity" is a single large document with unique keys that I'm trying to get the value from, based on key name (when it matches value from the "people" document).

What I'm trying to achieve is this output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Pete",
    "occupation": "baker”,
    “activity:” “bakes”
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mike",
    "occupation": "painter”,
    “activity”: “paints”
  }
]
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Not clear is your document "activity" in different collection or you just want to map the document on the fly to the people documents  , how the activity document looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your database and data model, it seems like a poor model.
If the data model was different (see below), the query would be quite simple.  Given that, here's one way you could generate your desired output with your model.

```js
db.people.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
      "from": "activity",
      "let": { occ: "$occupation" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$replaceWith": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                "as": "kv",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$kv.k", "$$occ" ] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "activity"
    }
  },
  { "$set": {
      "activity": {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "v",
          "input": {
            "$first": {
              "$objectToArray": { "$first": "$activity" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unset": "_id" }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iCvhTu9VykP).

If your `activity` collection has this model...

```json
[
  {
    "occupation": "baker",
    "activity": "bakes"
  },
  {
    "occupation": "painter",
    "activity": "paints"
  }
]
```

... then the query could be:

```js
db.people.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
      "from": "activity",
      "localField": "occupation",
      "foreignField": "occupation",
      "as": "activity"
    }
  },
  { "$set": { "activity": { "$first": "$activity.activity" } } },
  { "$unset": "_id" }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G7N0zhmXont).

Comment: Wow, amazing. Unfortunately I have no control over the structure of the collection, so even though the solution is complex I'm very happy to have something that works. Thanks!

Comment: @2dumb Glad it helped. Is it possible for you to write to the same database? If so, you could create a new data model with a single aggregation pipeline to either create a new collection or just add docs to the current `activity` collection.